# Mysql arithmetic

Tags: mysql

I have the following code which goes through a table that has a table name and numbers for each row

For example

```
Barcelona | 3 | Milan   | 6
Inter     | 6 | Chelsea | 2
Barcelona | 8 | Madrid  | 2
Inter     | 2 | Parma   | 1
```

With the following code I want my result to be

```
Barcelona 11 8 3
Inter 8 3 5
```

So I get the goals scored the goals against and the difference however my query works for the first row but it doesn't take the difference in the second row

```
SELECT
    c.team1, 
    SUM(c.team1score) as GF,
    SUM(c.team2score) as GA,
    (c.team1score-c.team2score) as GD
FROM calendario AS c
GROUP BY c.team1
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: got it nevermind I'm not taking the sum for the last GD

Comment: If you figured out the solution, post it as an answer below, so that future Googlers can be enlightened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but maybe you need only to take difference between the two SUM values, like in this way :

```
 SELECT c.team1, sum(c.team1score) as GF, sum(c.team2score) as GA, (sum(c.team1score)-sum(c.team2score)) as GD
 FROM calendario c
 group by c.team1
```